# apply call with argument result_type="expand": Two cases which should be the same - but aren't

Tags: pandas, numpy

I don't understand why in some cases the result_type="expand" argument in apply leads to an error (due to unequal list lengths) why in other cases it doesn't produce the error. Maybe someone can explain to me as to why the second approach does not cause the same error as the first!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"x": ["A new result", "Some result"]})

#First approach (correctly results in an error cause of unequal length in output):
def get_list(row):
    if np.random.uniform()>0.5:
        return [i for i in range(5)]
    else:
        return [i for i in range(3)]

df.apply(get_list, axis=1, result_type='expand')

#Second approach: Does not result in an error (why?)
def split_it(x):
    return x.split() # will also produce output of unequal length!

v_split = np.frompyfunc(split_it,1,1)

df.apply(v_split, axis=1, result_type='expand') # does not throw any error
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the second approach is not expanding the lists, of different lengths, returned by `v_split` but assigns them to a single column named `x`:

```py
print(df.apply(v_split, axis=1, result_type='expand')) # will never raise an exception
# Output

                  x
0  [A, new, result]
1    [Some, result]
```

Whereas the first approach indeed tries to expand the lists, which can be of different lengths, returned by `get_list` to new columns.

So, if by chance the lists are all the same lengths, you get a dataframe with five columns:

```py
print(df.apply(get_list, axis=1, result_type='expand'))
# Output

   0  1  2  3  4
0  0  1  2  3  4
1  0  1  2  3  4
```

If not, `apply` will fail as expected and raise `ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length`